# XSL order of templates for nested elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file like so:

```
<text>
  <a>foo1</a>
  <a><b>foo2</b></a>
</text>
```

I have an XSL file designed to process `<a>` and `<a><b>` differently with templates 1 and 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- t1 -->
  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:element name="keep">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- t2 -->
  <xsl:template match="a/b" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expected that this would produce:

```
<text>
  <keep>foo1</keep>
</text>
```

Because t2 should match and 'ignore' `<a><b>foo2</a></b>` and I thought that it would take precedence over t1 (both t1 and t2 match `<a><b>` but t2 is simply later in the XSL). But the output is in fact:

```
<text>
  <keep>foo1</keep>
  <keep>foo2</keep>
</text>
```

In fact if I take t2 away the output is the same, so clearly it is not even matching `<a><b>`. I must be missing something: please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
<xsl:template match="a[b]" />
```

a template that matches `a` elements if they have a child element called `b`.

A template match like

```
<xsl:template match="a/b" />
```

does not match `a` elements, it matches `b` elements that have an `a` element as their parent. But in your original stylesheet, the XSLT processor is never prompted to find a matching template for `b` elements, that's why the code contained in this template (none) is never executed.

With this change, the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
  <keep>foo1</keep>

</text>
```

As you can see, it's *almost* the output you expected. With your XSLT processor, MSXSL, the empty line likely is not even there, because MSXSL strips the tree of whitespace-only nodes. But to have your stylesheet produce consistent results on any processor, the info below is still useful.

To remove the empty line in the output, add `xsl:strip-space` as a top-level element. Also, save yourself the trouble of typing `xsl:element name=...` if the element name is known beforehand. The whole stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- t1 -->
  <xsl:template match="a">
    <keep>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </keep>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- t2 -->
  <xsl:template match="a[b]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks @mathias-müller for the solution and the extra tips!